# Do the "AND" operation with the first column and the second list in the matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

My array is:

```
[[1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [6. 7. 6. 2. 2.]]
```

The last line is the sum of the columns.
I want to do the "AND" operation with the zero column and the first column in the matrix.
I use Program language is Python3.5.

I take the zero column and the first column.

```
[[1. 1.] 1
 [0. 1.] 0
 [0. 1.] 0
 [1. 1.] 1
 [1. 0.] 0
 [0. 1.] 0
 [1. 0.] 0
 [1. 1.] 1
 [1. 1.] 1
 [6. 7.]]
```

And count the results and save them in the list.

How can I do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "AND" operation? With you sample data, what would the result look like?

Comment: I take the zero column and the second column.

Comment: And do what with them?

Comment: I edit my question.

Comment: Do you use numpy?

Comment: Yes! I use numpy for my array.

Comment: Hi @user10008500, I think my solution is cleaner using python list comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the question but maybe something like this:

```
arr = [[1., 1.], [0., 1.], [0., 1.], [1., 1.], [1., 0.], [0., 1.], [1., 0.], [1., 1.], [1., 1.], [6., 7.]]
for a in arr:
    if (a[0] and a[1]):
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
```

Comment: Yes. But the [6., 7.] don't need

Comment: add condition if a[0] a[1] not equal 0 or 1 return null

Comment: sorry, I don't undersand.

Comment: @user10008500 like this: if (( a[0] == 0 or a[0] == 1) and ( a[1] == 0 or a[1] == 1))

Comment: @user10008500 yep, go on

Comment: @user10008500 if you want to count the 1's in the first 2 columns, given that there are only 1 and 0, you can do `sum([row[0] + row[1] for row in arr[:-1]])`.

Comment: Thank you everybody help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for s in list:
    s.append(int(s[0]) & int(s[1]))
```

or

```
anded = [int(s[0]) & int(s[1]) for s in list]
print(sum(anded))
```

All this code does is iterate over your list, and take the elements from position 0 and 1 from the sub-list, convert them to integers (looks like they were doubles before), bitwise and them and append the result to the sub-list. At the end when you get your sums, you can just use the same operation as with the result of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

If arr has type list you can try:

```
arr = [[1., 1.], [0., 1.], [0., 1.], [1., 1.], [1., 0.], [0., 1.], [1., 0.], [1., 1.], [1., 1.], [6., 7.]]

result = [int(row[0] and row[1]) for row in arr[:-1]]
print(result)
```

Output

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using numpy. Then you can simply take the slice of the array and apply the function [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) to this slice, which concatenates all elements in one big AND-operation. You have to configure the function to perform the operation along the desired axis with the particular argument `axis`.

---

**CODE**

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
              [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
              [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
              [1., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
              [1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
              [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
              [1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
              [1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
              [1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
              [6., 7., 6., 2., 2.]])

slice_a = a[0:-1, 0:2]                # Do the slicing, "0:-1" zeroth row to the second last row,
                                      #                 "0:2"  zeroth to the first column
and_slice = np.all(slice_a, axis=1)   # Perform the boolean operation

print( slice_a  ) 
print( and_a )
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
array([[1., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])
array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True])
```

---

**BONUS**

If you want the output to be a column vector add the argument `keepdims=True`:

```
and_slice = np.all(slice_a, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```